# What does the continue statement do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain why this causes an infinite loop even tho the continue from what I have been reading should "skip" the iteration

```
x = 0
while x < 50:

    if x == 33:
       print("I hit 33")
       continue
    else:
       pass
    print(x)
    x+=1
```

Comment: Indentation save lives in Python.  Please check the indentation in your code.  Also as it stands, your code will error out at `while x < 50`.

Comment: It doesn't. It throws a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: This isn't valid code. Please check it before posting.

Comment: `continue` is pointless in this context anyhow. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @martineau the `while` loop didn't have `:` previously and Tim was probably pointing that out

Comment: @Ares: Yes, I see now that the OP added it in an edit—so I'll delete my own earlier comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `continue` command restarts the innermost loop at the condition.

That means after `x` reaches `33`, `x += 1` will never execute because you will be hitting the `continue` and going back to the `while` line without running the rest of the code block.

`x` will forever be `33` so you will have a infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are skipping the increment that happens at the end of the `while` loop when you call `continue`. The following will automatically increment if you want to keep the `continue` statement:

```
for x in range(50):
    if x == 33:
        print("I hit 33")
        continue
    else:
        print(x)
```

Otherwise, delete the `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing [break and continue](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue).

- `continue` will skip to next iteration in innermost loop
- `break` will leave innermost loop

Answer (score 1):

`continue` goes to the **next** iteration. You want `break` which exits the loop. See:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5:
       continue
    if i == 8:
       break
    print(i)
```

outputs:

```
0
1
2
3
4
6
7
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing the code you're trying to get at is as follows, which will print out each integer from 0 - 50 (exclusive), except it will print "I hit 33" for the integer 33.

```
x = 0
while x < 50:
    if x == 33:
        print("I hit 33")
    else:
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

You really don't need the `continue` or `pass` in this instance.  `continue` continues with the next cycle of the nearest enclosing loop.  `pass` is usually only used as a placeholder when a block is expecting a statement but you're not ready to use the statement.